# click to direct download with javascript

Tags: javascript, svelte, dom-to-image

I tried the [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library to download a set of HTML div. The "to-image" part worked just fine, but after the `div` was converted to an image, I want it also downloaded directly as an image. But I can't do that.

The dom-to-image docs said you can create an anchor element, and put the attributes there, and activate with the `click()` function:

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'my-image-name.png';
link.href = dataUrl;
link.click();
```

here is the example I made with [svelte](https://svelte.dev/repl/df20ba97cb424b64bdb6da376360042a?version=3.55.1), it won't download, if I put the anchor as a child, I can't click the link. BUT, I can right-click and `open in new tab` or `open image in new tab` and also `save image as`. So I think there's no problem with the src/URL.

```
<script>
    import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image'
    let capture, display = false
    
    function close() {
        display = !display
        document.querySelector(".image").remove()
    }
    
    function save() {
        console.log("save")
        display = !display
        domtoimage.toPng(capture)
            .then(function (dataUrl) {
                let link = document.createElement('a');
                link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
                link.href = dataUrl;
                link.click(); //not working
                let img = new Image();
                img.src = dataUrl;
                img.className = "image"
                let show = document.querySelector(".show")
                show.appendChild(link).appendChild(img);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
                    //no error logged
            });
    }
</script>

<div class="capture" bind:this={capture}>
    <h1 >Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        <!-- long text just for example -->
    </p>
</div>

<button on:click={save}>
    save
</button>

<div class="show" class:display={display}>
    <button on:click={close}>
        close
    </button>
</div>


<style>
    .capture {
        background-color:cornflowerblue;
        padding:1rem;
        color:white
    }
    h1 {
        background-color:lavender;
        padding:1rem;
        color:coral
    }
    .show {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        display:none;
    }
    .display {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

**UPDATE**
I recreate the code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/louislugas/pen/yLqWoZW?editors=0011) and it works, so it's a svelte problem? or just the svelte REPL environment problem? I need to implement in my own svelte environment later.

Answer (score 0):

The REPL does some click/navigation interception. The given code should work in a real environment.

Comment: I'll try it in my local later, or should I put `preventDefault()`?  -- preventDefault not working